# stop score increment if correct radiobutton is checked several times

Tags: java, android, radio-button

i have 2 radioGroup questions, when the correct answer is checked, the result increased by 20 as expected, but the problem that when pressing several times on correct radiobutton, it keeps on increasing score (result), I want the score (result) be increased only once even the correct radiobutton is pressed several times! also, how to reset all answers of all questions to restart the quiz again?, thanks in advance

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="com.example.nour.quiz.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/android_pyramids_image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Q1"
            style="@style/QuestionsTextStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:text="@string/Q1" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/age"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/hint1"
            android:inputType="number"
            style="@style/AnswersTextStyle"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Q2"
            style="@style/QuestionsTextStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:text="@string/Q2" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/pharoahName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/hint2"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            style="@style/AnswersTextStyle"/>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Q3"
            style="@style/QuestionsTextStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:text="@string/Q3" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroupOne"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/yesAnswer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="result"
                android:text="@string/RadioButton1"
                style="@style/AnswersTextStyle"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/noAnswer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="result"
                android:text="@string/RadioButton2"
                style="@style/AnswersTextStyle"/>

        </RadioGroup>


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Q4"
            style="@style/QuestionsTextStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:text="@string/Q4" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/wonderOne"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:onClick="wonderOne"
                android:text="@string/CheckBox1"
                style="@style/AnswersTextStyle"/>

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/wonderTwo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:onClick="wonderTwo"
                android:text="@string/CheckBox2"
                style="@style/AnswersTextStyle"/>

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/wonderThree"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:onClick="wonderThree"
                android:text="@string/CheckBox3"
                style="@style/AnswersTextStyle"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Q5"
            style="@style/QuestionsTextStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:text="@string/Q5" />


        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroupTwo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/FranceAnswer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="FranceButton"
                android:text="@string/RadioButton3"
                style="@style/AnswersTextStyle"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/EnglandAnswer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="EnglandButton"
                android:text="@string/RadioButton4"
                style="@style/AnswersTextStyle"/>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/EgyptAnswer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="EgyptButton"
                android:text="@string/RadioButton5"
                style="@style/AnswersTextStyle"/>

        </RadioGroup>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@drawable/button"
                android:onClick="result"
                android:text="@string/button" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

```
 private int result = 0;
EditText age, name;
CheckBox wonderOne, wonderTwo, wonderThree;
RadioGroup radioGroup1, radioGroup2;
RadioButton yes, no, france, england, egypt;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    age = findViewById(R.id.age);
    name = findViewById(R.id.pharoahName);
    radioGroup1 = findViewById(R.id.radioGroupOne);
    radioGroup2 = findViewById(R.id.radioGroupTwo);
    wonderOne = findViewById(R.id.wonderOne);
    wonderTwo = findViewById(R.id.wonderTwo);
    wonderThree = findViewById(R.id.wonderThree);
}


//Result of Q4
// Do nothing if wonder one is checked
public void wonderOne(View view) {
    if (wonderTwo.isChecked() && wonderThree.isChecked() && !wonderOne.isChecked()) {
        result += 20;

    } else {
    }

}
//Result of Q4
//Add 20 to result if wonder two is checked
public void wonderTwo(View view) {
    if (wonderTwo.isChecked() && wonderThree.isChecked() && !wonderOne.isChecked()) {
        result += 20;

    } else {
    }
}
//Add 20 to result if wonder three is checked
public void wonderThree(View view) {
    if (wonderTwo.isChecked() && wonderThree.isChecked() && !wonderOne.isChecked()) {
        result += 20;

    } else {
    }

}
//Result of Q5
public void FranceButton(View view) {
    int radioId = radioGroup2.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    france = findViewById(radioId);

}
//Result of Q5
public void EnglandButton(View view) {
    int radioId = radioGroup2.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    england = findViewById(radioId);

}
//Result of Q5
public void EgyptButton(View view) {
    int radioId = radioGroup2.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    egypt = findViewById(radioId);

    //Add 20 to result if Egypt is checked
    if (egypt.isChecked()) {
        result += 20;
    } else {
    }
}
//Result of Q3


//This method is called when submit answers button is clicked
public void result(View view) {

    //Result of Q1
    // This method is to prevent app from crashing if age is not entered
    try {
        //Range of accepted age is between 21 & 50 years old
        int range = Integer.parseInt(age.getText().toString());

        //Add 20 to result if age is between 21 & 50
        if (range >= 21 && range <= 50) {
            result += 20;

        } else {

        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("you must enter your age");

    }

    //Result of Q2
    // Add 20 to result if Name = Cleopatra
    if (name.getText().toString().equals("Cleopatra")) {
        result += 20;

    } else {

    }

    //Result of Q3
    yes = findViewById(R.id.yesAnswer);
    no = findViewById(R.id.noAnswer);

    if (yes.isChecked() && !no.isChecked()){
        result += 20;
    }


    //Calculate final result
    if (result >= 60) {
        ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.android_pyramids_image_view);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.pyramids_hdpi);


        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your result is: " + result + "/100" +
                ", Congratulations! YOU won a trip to Egypt.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your result is: " + result + "/100" +
                ", Hard luck this time!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple solutions for this. One of them is to disable the radio group buttons if an answer is selected, so the user won't be able to change their option or select the same option again.

This can be done by disabling the radioButtons for each radioGroup after the user has selected an option in it by

```
for (int i = 0; i < radioGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
       radioGroup.getChildAt(i).setEnabled(false);
}
```

Regarding the second part of your question, simply clear each element that is required for the Quiz by using one of the below:

```
radioButton.setChecked(false);
checkBox.setChecked(false);
editText.getText().clear();
```

If you prefer not to disable the already answered questions of the quiz, you could have a Boolean variable (e.g. `private boolean answeredQuizSection1 = false;`) for each section of the quiz, with initial value `false` and if the user selects any answer on that section, you change the respective variable to `true`. You would just add this variable in the condition of the if statement that increases the result points.

Comment: thanks alot Alexios,it worked very well for the 1st part (disabling the radioButtons), also it worked for resetting all the answers except for (radioButtons) the app crached,when i deleted the code for (disabling the radioButton) it worked and cleared all the answers, so what can i do?....also i want to reset the (result) because it still counting on the last answers even the last answers are reseted,another one more thing please, when the result is above 60 the app shows a toast message + an image i want to remove the image also when the answers and result are resetted can i do that? @Alexios

Comment: Could you please post the exception when the application crashes? Regarding resetting the result if I understood correctly, it seems reasonable to reset the variable to zero immediately after the Toast has been shown to the user. Regarding the image, if you want to make it invisible you can just call `imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`. If you want to reset the image to the previous resource that was appearing, you should store somewhere that resource before changing the image view and reset it afterwards. @KarkoraCaro

Comment: finally i fix all the errors and this the final code:
radioGroup1.clearCheck();
            //Enabling the radioButtons again for each radioGroup
            for (int i = 0; i < radioGroup1.getChildCount(); i++) {
                radioGroup1.getChildAt(i).setEnabled(true);
            }
            radioGroup2.clearCheck();
            //Enabling the radioButtons again for each radioGroup
            for (int x = 0; x < radioGroup2.getChildCount(); x++) {
                radioGroup2.getChildAt(x).setEnabled(true);
            }
            result = 0;

Comment: and to remove the image i added your code after the 2nd toast image:  } else {
            //Remove pyramid image
            ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.android_pyramids_image_view);
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.pyramids_hdpi);
            imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);      you really helped me, thanks very much @Alexios

Comment: @KarkoraCaro What made you unaccept my answer? Is there something I could improve on my answer?

Comment: I unaccepted your answer only because I finally find the correct codes for all my errors, your answer was very helpful for me, I added some adjustments to it and it worked very well, I only wanted to share my final correct answer so as it could be helpful to other persons. I wanted to keep your answer but Unfortunately, the site accepts only one answer. @Alexios

Answer (score 0):

(Final correct answer)

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private int result = 0;
EditText age, name;
CheckBox wonderOne, wonderTwo, wonderThree;
RadioGroup radioGroup1, radioGroup2;
RadioButton yes, no, france, england, egypt;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    age = findViewById(R.id.age);
    name = findViewById(R.id.pharoahName);
    radioGroup1 = findViewById(R.id.radioGroupOne);
    radioGroup2 = findViewById(R.id.radioGroupTwo);
    wonderOne = findViewById(R.id.wonderOne);
    wonderTwo = findViewById(R.id.wonderTwo);
    wonderThree = findViewById(R.id.wonderThree);
}

//Result of Q3
public void yesButton(View view) {
    int radioId = radioGroup1.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    yes = findViewById(radioId);
    //Add 20 to result if yes is checked
    if (yes.isChecked()) {
        result += 20;
        //disabling the radioButtons after the user has selected an option in it
        //This is to prevent rechecking of checked radioButton and stop score (result) increment
        for (int i = 0; i < radioGroup1.getChildCount(); i++) {
            radioGroup1.getChildAt(i).setEnabled(false);
        }

    }else{

    }
}
//Result of Q3
public void noButton(View view) {
    int radioId2 = radioGroup1.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    no = findViewById(radioId2);
    if (no.isChecked()){
        //disabling the radioButtons after the user has selected an option in it
        //This is to prevent rechecking of checked radioButton and stop score (result) increment
        for (int i = 0; i < radioGroup1.getChildCount(); i++) {
            radioGroup1.getChildAt(i).setEnabled(false);
        }

    }else {

    }
}

//Result of Q4
// Do nothing if wonder one is checked
public void wonderOne(View view) {
    if (wonderTwo.isChecked() && wonderThree.isChecked() && !wonderOne.isChecked()) {
        result += 20;

    } else {
    }

}
//Result of Q4
//Add 20 to result if wonder two is checked
public void wonderTwo(View view) {
    if (wonderTwo.isChecked() && wonderThree.isChecked() && !wonderOne.isChecked()) {
        result += 20;

    } else {
    }
}

//Result of Q4
//Add 20 to result if wonder three is checked
public void wonderThree(View view) {
    if (wonderTwo.isChecked() && wonderThree.isChecked() && !wonderOne.isChecked()) {
        result += 20;

    } else {
    }

}
//Result of Q5
public void FranceButton(View view) {
    int radioId = radioGroup2.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    france = findViewById(radioId);
    if (france.isChecked()){
        //disabling the radioButtons after the user has selected an option in it
        //This is to prevent rechecking of checked radioButton and stop score (result) increment
        for (int x = 0; x < radioGroup2.getChildCount(); x++) {
            radioGroup2.getChildAt(x).setEnabled(false);
        }
    }else {

    }
}

//Result of Q5
public void EnglandButton(View view) {
    int radioId = radioGroup2.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    england = findViewById(radioId);
    if (england.isChecked()){
        //disabling the radioButtons after the user has selected an option in it
        //This is to prevent rechecking of checked radioButton and stop score (result) increment
        for (int x = 0; x < radioGroup2.getChildCount(); x++) {
            radioGroup2.getChildAt(x).setEnabled(false);
        }
    }else {

    }

}
//Result of Q5
public void EgyptButton(View view) {
    int radioId = radioGroup2.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    egypt = findViewById(radioId);

    //Add 20 to result if Egypt is checked
    if (egypt.isChecked()) {
        result += 20;
        //disabling the radioButtons after the user has selected an option in it
        //This is to prevent rechecking of checked radioButton and stop score (result) increment
        for (int x = 0; x < radioGroup2.getChildCount(); x++) {
            radioGroup2.getChildAt(x).setEnabled(false);
        }
    } else {
    }
}
//Result of Q3


//This method is called when submit answers button is clicked
public void result(View view) {

    //Result of Q1
    // This method is to prevent app from crashing if age is not entered
    try {
        //Range of accepted age is between 21 & 50 years old
        int range = Integer.parseInt(age.getText().toString());

        //Add 20 to result if age is between 21 & 50
        if (range >= 21 && range <= 50) {
            result += 20;

        } else {

        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("you must enter your age");

    }

    //Result of Q2
    // Add 20 to result if Name = Cleopatra
    if (name.getText().toString().equals("Cleopatra")) {
        result += 20;

    } else {

    }

    //Calculate final result
    if (result >= 60) {
        //Display pyramid image
        ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.android_pyramids_image_view);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.pyramids_hdpi);
        imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        //Display Toast message
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your result is: " + result + "/100" +
                ", Congratulations! YOU won a trip to Egypt.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //Clear all answers and reset result to zero to restart quiz
        name.getText().clear();
        age.getText().clear();
        wonderOne.setChecked(false);
        wonderTwo.setChecked(false);
        wonderThree.setChecked(false);
        radioGroup1.clearCheck();
        //Enabling the radioButtons again for each radioGroup
        for (int i = 0; i < radioGroup1.getChildCount(); i++) {
            radioGroup1.getChildAt(i).setEnabled(true);
        }
        radioGroup2.clearCheck();
        //Enabling the radioButtons again for each radioGroup
        for (int x = 0; x < radioGroup2.getChildCount(); x++) {
            radioGroup2.getChildAt(x).setEnabled(true);
        }
        result = 0;
    } else {
        //Remove pyramid image
        ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.android_pyramids_image_view);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.pyramids_hdpi);
        //This code to make pyramid image visible again after removal by wrong answers
        imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        //Display Toast message
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your result is: " + result + "/100" +
                ", Hard luck this time!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //Clear all answers and reset result to zero to restart quiz
        name.getText().clear();
        age.getText().clear();
        wonderOne.setChecked(false);
        wonderTwo.setChecked(false);
        wonderThree.setChecked(false);
        radioGroup1.clearCheck();
        //Enabling the radioButtons again for each radioGroup
        for (int i = 0; i < radioGroup1.getChildCount(); i++) {
            radioGroup1.getChildAt(i).setEnabled(true);
        }
        radioGroup2.clearCheck();
        //Enabling the radioButtons again for each radioGroup
        for (int x = 0; x < radioGroup2.getChildCount(); x++) {
            radioGroup2.getChildAt(x).setEnabled(true);
        }

        result = 0;

    }
}
```

}